# Can't get any MYSQL Join statements to work

Tags: mysql, join

I can't even get a very simple Join statement to work.  Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (Left) JOIN (Right) ON (Left.id=Right.id)";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "query: " . $query . "<br>result: " . $result . "<br>num rows: " . $num_rows;
```

And here is what it outputs:

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in xxxx\join.php on line 16

query: SELECT * FROM (Left) JOIN (Right) ON (Left.id=Right.id)

result:

num rows:

I used the exact same code on a website with a different host and it worked fine, but I can't get anything to work on this one.  I have never used Join statements before this so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it might not be working because of something that my host has disabled.  I am using Ipower for this website.

Comment: are your tables really named left and right?  those are reserved words and may have to be put in [] to work.  and don't select * always define field names.

Comment: It could be connection problem (wrong username/password for example). Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are truly named Left and Right (Seriously consider renaming them) then the following syntax will work:

```
SELECT * FROM `Left` JOIN `Right` ON `Left`.id=`Right`.id
```

However, I would strongly advise renaming those tables because Left and Right are reserved keywords and you will run across more syntactical problems by using those table names without escaping them. Your query as currently written is syntactically incorrect because  of your use of Left/Right as table names.

I'm really not sure what you were trying to do with those parenthesis.

```
(Left) JOIN (Right)
```

means

```
LEFT JOIN RIGHT
```

Which is obvious nonsense. You MUST escape the words LEFT and RIGHT in your JOIN clause.

Answer (score -2):

You could try adding "inner" just before the "join".

That would be my first guess - reason - it's actually an inner join.

Second guess would be to Re-write as follows.

SELECT *
 FROM (Left) , (Right) 
where Left.id=Right.id

Removing the join keyword from the SQL entirely.

Am guessing the 'join' keyword is causing problems.

Comment: How could the `JOIN` keyword be causing problems?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (Left) , (Right) where Left.id=Right.id` will not work (Syntax Error) The comma would be the same as the INNER JOIN keyword.  The words LEFT and RIGHT must be escaped in the JOIN clause. PERIOD.